# Using Identities to simplify expression

Tags: trigonometry, chain-rule

I have the following expression which is supposed to be solved by chain rule to find dw/dt

$w$ = $5 \cos(xy)$ $-$ $\sin(xz)$ where $x = 1/t$ , $y=t$ , $z=t^3$

My final answer is ( added wolfram results just to be sure. They are the same as mine)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvTUv.gif)

And following is the answer that I want to get.

Result = $-2t \cos t^2$

I am trying to solve it through different Identities but of no luck

NOTE: This is actualy a question from Calculus (10 Edition) by Howard Anton Exercise 13.5 Q9

Comment: So which is the correct statement of the problem? The original one or the edited version (which invalidates the "final answer" you got)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use direct substitution for $t$ in $x$, $y$ and $z$.  One of the first terms will be a constant once the values of $t$ are substituted in.

**ANSWER:**

For $$w  = 5 \cos(xy) - \sin(xz)$$ where $$x=1/t, y=t, z=t^3$$

let's simplify in terms of $t$.  $xy$ in this case is $\frac {1}{t} \times t$ or **$1$**.  $xz$ is $\frac {1}{t} \times t^3$ or **$t^2$**.  Thus we have **$$w = 5 \cos 1 - \sin t^2$$**

Taking the derivative of $w$ with respect to $t$ is easy.  $5 \cos 1$ is a constant, so that derivative will be $0$.  Taking the derivative of $-\sin t^2$ by using the chain rule leaves us with $$-2t \cos t^2$$

Comment: You know you just save me a lot of hours with that Edit. All this time I was reading the question wrong since there were no brackets in actual questions. Got my answer as in the textbook - Thanks

Comment: No problem!  I was looking at the equation and saying to myself, "perhaps they meant $xy$ vs. $x(y)$" so I cleaned it up a little and verified it for myself..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for such a reduction to work: evaluate the two expressions at an easy-to-calculate point (e.g. $t=1/\pi$). The values are numerically different, so the two expressions are not equal. Are you sure you have copied the statement of the problem accurately?

Comment: Just to assure that I have written the question correctly look at the following links                                                                                                                               **Actual Question (Textbook) :** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0ebicVSUGGTjc4TzVtLUczQ1E/view                             **Actual Answer (Textbook) :** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0ebicVSUGGbk1IX1dFUjZfVUk/view                                             **My Answer :** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0ebicVSUGGdkVpM28zdmRaR2M/view

Comment: I'm sorry but I was solving the question wrong. It was **w  = 5cos⁡(xy) − sin(xz)** instead of **w  = 5cos⁡(x)y − sin(x)z**

Comment: Should I remove the questions because it doesn't reflect the actual reason for it was asked ?